OpenIddict encrypting of jwt
Using OpenIddict 3, there was a 'enc' value set in the authorization.header, indicating that the accessToken was encrypted.
Now that I've upgraded to OpenIddict 5.6, this value no longer exists (is null). I haven't found anything to do with this change in the OpenIddict upgrade docs, in their samples or on the Github page.
The documentation says

By default, OpenIddict enforces encryption for all the token types it supports.
and so I would expect it to still work.
When upgrading I followed the upgrade steps to version 4 and then to version 5 as written on the OpenIddict site.

Does anyone have any insight into this change and how to add encryption to the jwt again?
